Low VIF in conditional model but high in zero-inflated model
I am using glm ZINB to make models that predict abundance of frogs based on observations from 57 sites. I used the check_model function from the performance package and it shows that the best model has low vif in the conditional model (vif<5) but high vif in the zero-inflated model (up to 50)(I have attached a picture below). I am a novice in the statistic field and I am wondering how should I handle these results. I know that variables with vif>5 should not be combined in glms but I am not sure of how it works for the two models in zero-inflated glms.


Don't do anything. A VIF is a summary of how correlated variables are. It doesn't mean anything about whether you should keep a variable in a model. Keep the variables you want to include. A large standard error reflects real uncertainty that should be retained and respected.

Hi Noah, thanks for your reply. You are right, the zero-inflated model has high standard error (up to 171). 34 of the 57 sites had frogs recorded and the check_zero-inflation function from performance does not show zero-inflation (it predicts 21/22 zeros depending on the model), so I guess that the zero-inflated model has a really small sample size. Would you suggest ditching the zero-inflated and just use GLMs NB even though the zero-inflated models have lower AIC (around 210 in the zero-inflated and 220 in the non zero-inflated)? Or otherwise use bootstrapping to reduce standard error?
